# Printing full stack trace of all queries in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

In Spring Boot, I want to log all executed queries and recursively their callers methods and classes.

For example if the logged query is `Select * from users`, then I want something like this:

```
ServiceA.findAllUsers() > UserRepository.findAll() > Select * from users;
```

How could I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: You are mixing some of the stuff, with logger you can get the caller, callee, and further query with the help of application property entry. I agree the format is not what you are looking for, however, my recommendation will be not to achieve it with the help of AOP, reason behind doing something manually via code will not be easy to implement and maintain further.

Comment: Thank you @NirajJha for your comment. At this point I just don't care about maintainability. I'm just debugging and trying find all running queries and their corresponding repository and service classes (by print them to the console). Setting which property can help me about this?

Comment: It sounds you need indeed an aspect with something like `new Exception().printStackTrace();` to get the callers.
I would consider also playing with the logger to find the query, here for example, with Hibernate: <logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="TRACE" /> <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG" />

Comment: The property you can use `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`, although not recommended as adds everything to console output.